# Error in installing Open-CV with ffmpeg

Tags: c, opencv, ffmpeg, makefile, cmake

I am trying to install the library Open-CV working on on Ubuntu 11.04.

I followed all instructions found in the [InstallationGuide](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide_Linux).

However after installing with success I realized that I hadn't `FFMPEG` support because in my configuration file `FFMPEG` was disabled:

```
Video I/O: 
--     DC1394 1.x:                 NO 
--     DC1394 2.x:                 YES 
--     FFMPEG:                     NO 
--       codec:                    YES 
--       format:                   YES 
--       util:                     YES 
--       swscale:                  NO 
--       gentoo-style:             YES 
--     GStreamer:                  YES 
--     UniCap:                     NO 
--     PvAPI:                      NO 
--     V4L/V4L2:                   Using libv4l 
--     Xine:                       NO
```

So I tried to rebuild everything after installing FFMEPG as decribed [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095).

After configuring installation with the instruction

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON ../OpenCV-2.3.1
```

I ran the make command getting this error:

```
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_test_calib3d] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/calib3d/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_calib3d.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is the point of compilation where the error is coming out:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_calib3d
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_analysis_headerout'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_set_out_samplerate'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_set_disable_reservoir'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_encode_buffer'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vaUnmapBuffer'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vaDestroyBuffer'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `th_comment_clear'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `x264_param_default'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `x264_param_apply_profile'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_set_brate'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_headers'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `faacEncGetCurrentConfiguration'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_analysis_blockout'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_info_clear'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_analysis_buffer'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `th_comment_init'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vaCreateBuffer'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_set_bWriteVbrTag'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `faacEncSetConfiguration'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `th_encode_ctl'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `D_IF_decode'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `faacEncGetDecoderSpecificInfo'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_block_clear'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_close'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_encode'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_set_VBR'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `Encoder_Interface_init'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_analysis'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_get_framesize'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `faacEncOpen'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_init'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `th_encode_packetout'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_set_quality'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `Decoder_Interface_exit'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `th_encode_alloc'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_encode_setup_vbr'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `th_info_clear'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_set_in_samplerate'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_reconfig'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `x264_param_apply_fastfirstpass'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_set_VBR_quality'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_set_mode'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `D_IF_init'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_set_num_channels'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `faacEncEncode'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_encode_setup_managed'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `Encoder_Interface_exit'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `Decoder_Interface_init'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vaRenderPicture'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_encode_ctl'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `th_info_init'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_analysis_init'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_delayed_frames'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `x264_param_parse'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `th_encode_free'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `D_IF_exit'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_dsp_clear'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `Decoder_Interface_Decode'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vaMapBuffer'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_block_init'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `x264_bit_depth'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `x264_picture_init'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_close'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_open_120'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `faacEncClose'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vaEndPicture'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_encode_flush'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_encode_buffer_interleaved'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_comment_init'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_comment_clear'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_init_params'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `x264_param_default_preset'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_encode_setup_init'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_bitrate_addblock'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_comment_add_tag'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `th_encode_flushheader'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `lame_encode_buffer_int'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `th_encode_ycbcr_in'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_bitrate_flushpacket'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_analysis_wrote'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vorbis_info_init'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `Encoder_Interface_Encode'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1: undefined reference to `vaBeginPicture'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

can anybody please tell me what's the problem with installation process I'm following?

Why is there this library referentiation error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These errors are from the linkage process and they often mean that you are missing some libraries on your system, or they are in a location that is not being search by the build process.

I suggest you Google these symbols to know what are the packages you need to install.

**EDIT:**

To summarize the chat we had in private, the main issue was that x264 was being built statically. **It's essential to build the shared version of the library** with `--enable-shared`. The OP recommends adding `--prefix=/usr/local` in all configuration options.

Comment: googling didn't help much, I found another linking error, but due to a different problem (https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1077). Can you please help me understand why build process isn't finding libraries it's looking for? should I update some environment variable? any other ideas? thks a lot!

Comment: maybe I should add a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` in order to specify the path of x264 and ffmpeg libraries I installed?

Comment: When you executed **cmake** after installing ffmpeg, were you able to see in the output text that it actually found ffmpeg? Also a quick search on Google revealed that some of these symbols are included in the package **libmp3lame0**, do you have it installed?

Comment: yes, here is my apt-get output: `libmp3lame0 is already the newest version.`

Comment: How about these packages: **libmp3lame-dev** , **libvorbis-dev** , **libfaac-dev** ? They should be installed in `/usr/lib`! Also, I think you need to execute `sudo make install` inside x264 sources dir since you've compiled it by hand, else it won't be installed on the system. IF you don't do this, you'll need to add the **x264 .so** path to LD_LIBRADY_PATH. **But one of the most important things is** to be sure that you can use ffmpeg on the cmd-line and it works. Check the cmds under the section [Using FFmpeg and x264](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095).

Comment: 1) I have all the packages listed.
2a) I installed x264 in /usr/local/lib by doing `make` and then `sudo make install`
2b) Probelm is that after doing `sudo make install` I can't find a file `x264.so` but just a `x264.a` in dir `/usr/local/lib`.
3) I'll try and let you know if it works.

thks a lot for help..

Comment: The **.a** is the **static** version of the library. You need to build the **shared** version of the library (i.e. **.so**). There must be some cmd-line switch that enables that during the build of x264.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6550/discussion-between-matteo-and-karlphillip)