# how to Compile OpenCV in Linux 11.04

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake

I am trying to compile OpenCV with cmake but I keep getting the following errors.

```
[ 73%] Building CXX object src/highgui/CMakeFiles/highgui.dir/cvcap_ffmpeg.o
In file included from /usr/include/libavutil/avutil.h:81:0,
from /usr/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:30,
from /usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h:56,
from /vol/cruk/Packages/irtk_ubuntu1104/vdm108/OpenCV200w/src/highgui/cvcap_ffmpeg.cpp:97:
/usr/include/libavutil/common.h: In function ‘int32_t av_clipl_int32(int64_t)’:
/usr/include/libavutil/common.h:154:47: error: ‘UINT64_C’ was not declared in this scope
/vol/cruk/Packages/irtk_ubuntu1104/vdm108/OpenCV200w/src/highgui/cvcap_ffmpeg.cpp: In       member function ‘virtual bool CvCapture_FFMPEG::grabFrame()’:
/vol/cruk/Packages/irtk_ubuntu1104/vdm108/OpenCV200w/src/highgui/cvcap_ffmpeg.cpp:546:9:   warning: ‘int avcodec_decode_video(AVCodecContext*, AVFrame*, int*, const uint8_t*, int)’ is   deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:3452)
/vol/cruk/Packages/irtk_ubuntu1104/vdm108/OpenCV200w/src/highgui/cvcap_ffmpeg.cpp:548:54:     warning: ‘int avcodec_decode_video(AVCodecContext*, AVFrame*, int*, const uint8_t*, int)’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:3452)
/vol/cruk/Packages/irtk_ubuntu1104/vdm108/OpenCV200w/src/highgui/cvcap_ffmpeg.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG::open(const char*, int, double, CvSize, bool)’:
/vol/cruk/Packages/irtk_ubuntu1104/vdm108/OpenCV200w/src/highgui/cvcap_ffmpeg.cpp:1199:8: warning: ‘AVOutputFormat* guess_format(const char*, const char*, const char*)’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h:787)
/vol/cruk/Packages/irtk_ubuntu1104/vdm108/OpenCV200w/src/highgui/cvcap_ffmpeg.cpp:1199:41: warning: ‘AVOutputFormat* guess_format(const char*, const char*, const char*)’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h:787)
/vol/cruk/Packages/irtk_ubuntu1104/vdm108/OpenCV200w/src/highgui/cvcap_ffmpeg.cpp:1213:7: warning: ‘AVFormatContext* av_alloc_format_context()’ is deprecated (declared at    /usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h:947)
/vol/cruk/Packages/irtk_ubuntu1104/vdm108/OpenCV200w/src/highgui/cvcap_ffmpeg.cpp:1213:31: warning: ‘AVFormatContext* av_alloc_format_context()’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h:947)
make[2]: *** [src/highgui/CMakeFiles/highgui.dir/cvcap_ffmpeg.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/highgui/CMakeFiles/highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have no idea as to why its doing this. I would really appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're compiling it with C++ compiler. If you do, you should define a `__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS` flag to make the whole thing successfully compile.

More info: [FFMPEG FAQ](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#I_0027m-using-libavutil-from-within-my-C_002b_002b-application-but-the-compiler-complains-about-_0027UINT64_005fC_0027-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues when trying to install `ffmpeg` support for `OpenCV`.

Check this SO question: [Error in installing Open-CV with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771334/error-in-installing-open-cv-with-ffmpeg): you'll find some indications and links to compilation tutorials.