# OpenCV, ffmpeg and eclipse on linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, opencv, ffmpeg

I'm writing a program using ffmpeg and OpenCV. for installing ffmpeg I have ran sudo apt-get install ffmpeg, and for opencv make & sudo make install.
Now I have made a project and need to tell eclipse where the headers and lib files are. So where are they?

Thanks,
Nahum

Comment: you can check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771334/error-in-installing-open-cv-with-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 0):

I don't run Debian, so these paths may be not be right for you, but generally packages using binary packages (via apt-get, rather than apt-src) install libraries in `/usr/lib` and include headers in `/usr/include`.

On my system the include directory for ffmpeg is `/usr/include/libavformat` and the include directory for opencv is `/usr/include/opencv` and `/usr/include/opencv2`.  Both libraries are in the default location of  `/usr/lib`.

If you know the name of the library, you can use the find and locate commands to look for its location. E.g `find / -iname name*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following commands. For ffmpeg:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs libavdevice libavformat libavfilter libavcodec libswscale libavutil
```

For OpenCV:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
```